# import 3ds files in Blender 2.80

Tags: import

I see there is no option for importing 3ds files in the File -> Import menu in Blender 2.80.

Does this mean importing 3ds files will no longer be supported in Blender?

Comment: The last I checked a daily build, 3ds import was broken. I believe that the beta has removed any addon that has obvious problems.  I would guess that 3ds import will be fixed eventually, but I've not found any official statement to that effect.

Comment: This is answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215548/119206

Answer (score 6):

The best solution I've seen so far is to open ver. 2.79, import the 3ds file in that, then copy and paste the entire screen to ver. 2.8.  You can then save to a .blend or .dae or .obj file from that.

Comment: You can also copy paste instead of saving it and opening it :)

Answer (score 3):

Like any other import/export tool of Blender, 3DS import-export is an addon, and need to be ported to Blender 2.8. If it hasn't been done, then it's unavailable until someone takes the job.

Answer (score 2):

I also got that , but there's something you can do about it , if you still got the last blender version 2.79 , you have to export the 3DS file into it in a new blender project and save it , go to blender 2.8 and go to append and find where you saved the project with a 3DS file and load it