# Export to format .3ds and .x Blender 2.9

Tags: export

I'm new to the forum here, so at the beginning I wanted to give all users a warm welcome. I am very new to using blender software. Until now, I have only used this software to overlay UV maps on simple objects made in an external program. Since Blender 2.8 / 2.9 came out, I started learning tutorials on how to model and apply materials and textures. I need them for use in external software. This is where the problem arose, because I need the files in the .3ds format and the directx .x format. These programs do not accept other formats (MALighting 3D, Christie Pandoras Box (Coolux)).
Is an addon planned for these formats? Maybe there are more people who need these formats and they will join the request for them?
And at this point, to which format added to 2.9 is it best to export the created projects containing the object, its UV map, material and possibly texture so that it can be opened in 2.79 without major data loss, and then exported to the above formats? I will be grateful for any answer. Best regards.

Comment: Hi and welcome @nasula! This site is no forum rather a Q&A site. I'd recommend take the tour to learn how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Seems there is an addon for 3ds available: https://developer.blender.org/T66329 see the first comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/148176/31447